# Select first element of srcset with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, split

Using selenium in Python, I have been able to successfully access some url's of an image I want to download. However, the image link is stored within a srcset image attribute. When I use get_attribute('srcset'), it returns a string with the 4 links. I just want the one. How would I go about doing this? Could I possibly just crop the string afterwards?

Here's the site that I am scraping from:

https://www.politicsanddesign.com/

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import pyautogui
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.politicsanddesign.com/')
img_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'responsive-image-wrapper']/img").get_attribute("srcset")
driver.get(img_url)
```

And here is what the img_url object looks like:

```
//images.ctfassets.net/00vgtve3ank7/6f38yjnNcU1d6dw0jt1Uhk/70dfbf208b22f7b1c08b7421f910bb36/2020_HOUSE_VA-04_D-MCEACHIN..jpg?w=400&fm=jpg&q=80 400w, //images.ctfassets.net/00vgtve3ank7/6f38yjnNcU1d6dw0jt1Uhk/70dfbf208b22f7b1c08b7421f910bb36/2020_HOUSE_VA-04_D-MCEACHIN..jpg?w=800&fm=jpg&q=80 800w, //images.ctfassets.net/00vgtve3ank7/6f38yjnNcU1d6dw0jt1Uhk/70dfbf208b22f7b1c08b7421f910bb36/2020_HOUSE_VA-04_D-MCEACHIN..jpg?w=1200&fm=jpg&q=80 1200w, //images.ctfassets.net/00vgtve3ank7/6f38yjnNcU1d6dw0jt1Uhk/70dfbf208b22f7b1c08b7421f910bb36/2020_HOUSE_VA-04_D-MCEACHIN..jpg?w=1800&fm=jpg&q=80 1800w
```

But I'd like it to just be:

```
//images.ctfassets.net/00vgtve3ank7/6f38yjnNcU1d6dw0jt1Uhk/70dfbf208b22f7b1c08b7421f910bb36/2020_HOUSE_VA-04_D-MCEACHIN..jpg?w=400&fm=jpg&q=80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image seems to have an attribute called **currentSrc** which hold only the current value.

```
img_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'responsive-image-wrapper']/img").get_attribute("currentSrc")
driver.get(img_url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply split the value extracted from that web element.
As following:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import pyautogui
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.politicsanddesign.com/')
img_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'responsive-image-wrapper']/img").get_attribute("srcset")
img_urls = img_url.split(",")
```

Now `img_urls` is a **list** containing 3 URLs, so you can use it as following:

```py
driver.get(img_urls[0]) #open the first URL
driver.get(img_urls[1]) #open the second URL
driver.get(img_urls[2]) #open the third URL
```

Answer (score 0):

My inefficient solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import pyautogui
import time

# WILL NEED TO EVENTUALLY FIGURE OUT HOW TO WRAP ALL OF THIS INTO A FUNCTION OR LOOP TO DO IT FOR ALL DIV OBJECTS
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.politicsanddesign.com/')
img_url = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'responsive-image-wrapper']/img").get_attribute("srcset")
driver.get(img_url)
img_url2 = 'https:' + img_url.split(' 400w',1)[0]
driver.get(img_url2)
```